# How to add field to views programmatically at rendering phase?

Tags: 7, views

I need to do it all programmatically.

First I've added field to view query:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 */
function mm_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
    if ($view->name == 'my_view') {
        $query->fields['my_field_alias'] = array(
          'field' => 'my_field',
          'table' => 'my_table',
           'alias' => 'my_field_alias',
        );
    }
}
```

It seems to work, at least I'm seeing proper changes in SQL query.

Now I'm trying to add this field to display:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_view().
 */
function mm_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
    if ($view->name == 'my_view') {

        $view->add_item($view->current_display, 'field', 'my_table', 'my_field', array(
            'label' => 'My Label',
        ), 'my_field_alias');

    }
}
```

What I am missing?